# MUs from Memory Strips for Deep Data Mining?

Tags: android-netrunner

Do memory units provided by [MemStrips](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07046) count as free slots for [Deep Data Mining](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/13014)? The hard part is the "use the MU on MemStrips only for virus programs" note on the MemStrips.

For example, I’ve got 3 MUs used by some non-virus icebreakers, 1 MemStrips installed and I play the Deep Data Mining. What is the count of free MU to resolve this run ability? 1 or 4?

[image: Deep Data Mining]
[image: MemStrips]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory from MemStrips counts towards Deep Data Mining.  This is because Deep Data Mining doesn't actually use memory, it just looks at how much memory you have vs how much you are using.  MemStrips gives you memory, with a restriction on what types of programs can use it.

I've seen MemStrips used with [Data Folding](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07055) and [Overmind](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05053) for some powerful combo potential under this same principle.

Comment: Yes, the deck I've played against (casual play), used both Deep Data Mining and Data Folding with MemStrips. Also Savant via Dhegdheer were used.